# Entity Framework Null Foreign Keys on Seed

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm trying to figure out what is going on here. When I seed my database, my foreign key that it generates is always null. My model is simple:

```
public class PnlTarget
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PnlTargetId { get; set; }


    public ReferenceAsset Underlyer { get; set; }
    public decimal Target { get; set; }

    public virtual PnlSettings PnlSettings { get; set; }


}

public class PnlSettings
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int PnlSettingsId { get; set; }

    public ColloquialType Type { get; set; }

    public virtual PnlTarget SPTSX60 { get; set; }
    public virtual PnlTarget SPTXLVPR { get; set; }
    public virtual PnlTarget STBANKX { get; set; }
    public virtual PnlTarget SX5E { get; set; }
    public virtual PnlTarget RTY { get; set; }
    public virtual PnlTarget SPX { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    public DateTime LastEdited { get; set; }

    public string LastEditedBy { get; set; }

}
```

So it's a 1..0 to many relationship. When I seed it with something like this:

```
 PnlSettings vanillaAccelerator = new PnlSettings
        {
            PnlSettingsId = 1,
            Type = ColloquialType.VanillaAccelerator,
            RTY = new PnlTarget {Underlyer = ReferenceAsset.RTY, Target = (decimal) 0.004},
            SPX = new PnlTarget {Underlyer = ReferenceAsset.SPX, Target = (decimal) 0.004},
            SPTSX60 = new PnlTarget { Underlyer = ReferenceAsset.SPTSX60, Target = (decimal)0.004},
            SPTXLVPR = new PnlTarget { Underlyer = ReferenceAsset.SPTXLVPR, Target = (decimal)0.004},
            STBANKX = new PnlTarget { Underlyer = ReferenceAsset.STBANKX, Target = (decimal)0.004},
            SX5E = new PnlTarget { Underlyer = ReferenceAsset.SX5E, Target = (decimal)0.004},
            LastEdited = DateTime.Now,
            LastEditedBy = "SEED"
        };
```

My foreign key property is always null as illustrated here. I've tried implementing a foreign key property manually using the [ForeignKey] annotation but unfortunately it still generates this null column. Is this intended?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have your relationship set up in the database?

Comment: what is your mapping? for this to work, I think you'll have to map the inverse navigation property.